Auto numbering on questions
I'm designing a survey form builder. One proposed feature is to allow administrators to enable automatic numbering for questions and question groups. However, the software's robust logic and rule options mean that the sequence of numbers would need to dynamically adjust when a question or question group is skipped based on a rule.
We prefer to avoid dynamic numbering changes, as managers should consistently reference specific questions or question groups by their fixed number when communicating with mobile users.
In what scenarios would non-dynamic auto-numbering be beneficial, where the user is aware that they skipped a portion (as they see a missing sequence number)? I am considering scenarios with strictly defined templates, such as standard medical forms or forms for the construction industry based on standards and laws.
I have limited time and resources for user research. If you have any experience with this topic, I would appreciate it if you could share it.

Is there a reason why you can only have one or the other? Survey builders that I have used before allow automatic numbering for questions and question groups as an option (or for certain types of questions), so I am sure this is a better approach because you don't want to lock in one option and then have to come back and allow the other option later down the track.

Distinguish between the two kinds of users you have: The survey creator and the survey participant.
When I think of myself as a survey participant, what do I get from numbers on questions? I can't really think of any benefit: The progress needs to be shown elsewhere because the number alone does not tell me the overall count of questions. When there are gaps in numbering (and I notice), I would start wondering whether the program can't count. I certainly do not want to ponder the question of why a question has not been shown to me and thus a number is missing in the sequence. From my experience, don't show numbers on surveys (but do clearly show progress).
I did not create many surveys, esp. not in an regulated environment. If there's a need to link survey questions to some other set, this might be a reason to offer numbering. I'm only not sure whether this can always be automatic (i.e., whether the survey creator is allowed to change order). Be sure to understand the task of survey creation!

Even strictly defined templates based on standards and laws are subject to change, depending on the industry and the type of laws/regulations, so it isn't necessarily true that non-dynamic auto-numbering will usually be better.
I am thinking of user goals and behaviours rather than specific scenarios here, so an example might be a teacher who is setting exam questions and the exam format is set to a specific number, which means that you want automatic number to make sure that you have fulfilled the requirement and the automatic numbering helps you keep track of the total number of questions. However, you want to be able to dynamically update the number as you add or remove questions during the process. But maybe if you were only choosing questions out of a test bank and you are unlikely to add or remove questions, then it makes sense to have non-dynamic automatic numbering.
If you abstract this scenario, then there are use cases where the exact number of questions need to be met (or known), and you are unlikely to add or remove questions as part of the process because the contents have already been created elsewhere could be one situation. It doesn't sound like a typical use case, but maybe for your purpose it might be.
I would still suggest providing both options to the user rather than locking it to one or the other.
